# Width issues with complex scrolling behaviour in a Div

Tags: css, html, scroll, width

We need to display data in a scrollable div.

We have created a simplified fiddle to demonstrate:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQ5J/3/

The div contains two parts, a header and the content.

We want the Header to scroll horizontally along with the content, but to be fixed while vertical scrolling through the content.

We would like to achieve this completely in CSS if possible, we could solve it with jQuery I guess, but would prefer not to have to.

We have got most of the way there in CSS, but **we can't get the content div to stretch the full width of the header.**  Because, I guess, making the content div 100% of the containing div isn't the full width of the header.

In a little more depth:

HEADER:

We want the header to stay visible all the time when scrolling up/down through the content.   However the header is wider than the containing div so we do want it to scroll horizontally. (So no vertical scroll on the header, just horizontal).  We have got this part working. The header is a table.

CONTENT:

The content is a div that we want to scroll both horizontally (in sync with the header) and vertically (independently of the header).  This is the part we are having problems with.  The scroll is working well, but the width is not expanding to match the header.  It will only go as wide as the containing div.

*I know it's weird to have a table as the header and a div as the content, but due to legacy issues we need to keep it this way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure from the question if you can add addition elemnts to markup, but if you can, possible solution is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQ5J/8/

But there is possible problem — scrollbar will not be seen bu default. Is it ok this way?

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that looks really promising!  I'll give it a try in the full version of the divs in our app :)

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Thank you so much Alexy!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but this works.
-Wakeeta

```
body
{
    width:100%;
}

#outer_container
{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    border:6px solid #FF0000;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
#top_container
{
    display: block;
    width:1500px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#CC66FF;
}
#bottom_container
{
    height: 400px;
    width:1500px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFFF66;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
}
em
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Hi Wakeeta, thanks for your response.  Yes that does work, however the width of the header and content are variable so unless I use jQuery (an option we might have to resort to) I can't set the width to be a pixel value.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that it was variable width in the original post.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'll keep looking at it and let you know if I can figure anything else out.